# Adobe spam popup on my admin dashboard is bugging me

Tags: magento2, popup, spam

Since a few weeks i'm getting more and more spam on the admin dashboard from adobe, auto-installed and everything. It started with polls on the right side taking all the space and impossible to delete. Now it's entire help center buttons on the left.

I don't know how this is possible but today i have a "knowledge center bot window" from adobe called onboarding installed on the left menu of my dashboard. I'll add the screenshot.

Does anybody knows how to disable this crap and avoid futur install from adobe ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Rgds,

Marc

[image: magento 2 knowledge center bot window adobe]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Admin Panel -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Administrator.
and disable "Enable Admin Usage Tracking" under "Admin Usage".

Rgds,
Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, that did the trick. I never saw this option in the past.... and didn't update for at least a year ;) Hope they can't add other options like this haha.

Comment: Wow.. I love Adobe, how it just does one little thing and your entire Store admin panel is broken 

For anyone wondering, this is the related Github issues page - It breaks your admin panel, so if you have been having issues it's due to this. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it only appeared in June 2023.

The "pop up" is known as the "Knowledge Center Bot" or KC Bot.

Mine appeared out of nowhere and broke the JS that allowed the drop downs to appear in the menu on Stores >> Settings >> Configuration. The only way to turn it off as mentioned by @ChrisGru, is to get into one of those drop downs.

To do this, right click the ADVANCED tab and clicked "inspect" in the context menu. That allowed me access to the HTML, where I found the correct link and clicked, allowing me to turn off the KC Bot.

I am almost positive there would be other broken parts of the admin area because of this, so this comment might help you find your way around admin through the HTML.

**[EDIT]**

This issue is now being tracked in github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618

TLDR:

SSH...

```
bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0;
bin/magento cache:clean;
```

Answer (score 1):

> **You can run the below command to disable it.**

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0
```

> **If you want to disabled using Admin Go to Stores -> Configuration** -> **Admin -> Admin Usage -> Enable Admin Usage Tracking**

[image]

> You can also disable **Magento_AdminAnalytics** module using below command.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAnalytics
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for sharing, I just remove from my page too. Knowledge center does not allow page to load fully and I was forced to refresh entire page several times. Dont know what is the problem of Magento, why they create a complications for users, when entire competition try to make more user friendly platforms.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208439)