# How to remove Magento Help Center?

Tags: admin, helper, remove, loading, remove-block

The under the section of Backend Page is displayed Magento Help Center.

I am going to try for adding a category.

But it seems Magento Help Center interrupted it. As you look at the image, the loading status is continuous.

How to remove Magento Help Center?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adobe help center magento 2.4.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367788/adobe-help-center-magento-2-4-3)

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears a few days ago, it affected any Magento version that has the admin usage tracking enabled. A solution for this issue is to disable the admin usage feature. You can achieve that in one of the following ways:

1. To disable the admin usage feature via the command line:

```
bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0
bin/magento cache:clean
```

2. To disable the admin usage feature via the admin panel, navigate to Stores > Settings > Configurations > **Advanced** > **Admin** > **Admin Usage** section: set **Enable Admin Usage Tracking** field to **No**

Related links:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37627
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37632
- [Admin not loading - JS errors](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367763/admin-not-loading-js-errors)
- [Adobe help center magento 2.4.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367788/adobe-help-center-magento-2-4-3)
- [Adobe spam popup on my admin dashboard is bugging me](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355073/adobe-spam-popup-on-my-admin-dashboard-is-bugging-me)